# Error extracting with autofilter from one sheet to another

Tags: excel, vba

I have a destination sheet named DB_ABS which has the autofilter criteria in range b7:t7.  Below that is the destination range (a table named ABS_Table which has the same column in the and same order as the source sheet and the autofilter criteria.

The Source sheet is named DB_PBS and has a range holding the data in the same column order with the same field names.

Now when I run

```
Sub Autofilter()
'Unprotect_All
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set area = Sheets("DB_PBS").Range("PBS_Data")

area.AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
                    CriteriaRange:=Sheets("DB_ABS").Range("B8:O8"), _
                    CopyToRange:=Sheets("DB_ABS").Range("B12:O12"), _
                    Unique:=False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Sheet1.Select
'Protect_All
End Sub
```

I get an error 1004 The extract range has a missing or invalid field name.

I can´t figure out where the error is.

Comment: What is your actual range for named range `PBS_Data`?

Comment: The actual range is DB_PBS!A1:u20.  Thanks!